# Unknown symbol in thermostat schematic - two oblique lines inside a circle

Tags: symbol, diagram, thermostat

Full diagram:

[image: thermostat schematic]

[image: unknown symbol]What does the circle with two oblique lines inside it represent?

It's an [Emmeti Termec thermostat](https://www.emmeti.com/portal/en/products/termo/typology/62428_productTipology/family/62438_productFamily/products/62439_productItem/)

[image: physical device]

Comment: I'd guess it's a chiller if you're using the thermostat to control cooling connect the cooling machione there.

Comment: what does the instruction manual say about the connections to terminals `2` and `3`?

Comment: I wonder if its meant to be a mercury tilt switch